ASE-driven NWChem: How to include a Mulliken charges calculation?
I want to include the calculation of Mulliken charges into ASE-driven NWChem.
This is the input file I am using.
giving this error:
python3 HF_ase_nwchem.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/milias/work/git-projects/open-collection/theoretical_chemistry/software/nwchem-ase/runs/HF/ase_run/HF_ase_nwchem.py", line 8, in <module>
    hf.calc = NWChem(xc='PBE',basis='6-311G', property=dict('mulliken'))
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Any help, please?

You are trying to define a dict, but a dict is a collection of key-value pairs and you have only specified a single string. What you want is
hf.calc = NWChem(xc='PBE',basis='6-311G', property=dict(mulliken=None))

While the mulliken keyword in NWCHEM doesn't accept a value, you need to have something there to make a valid Python dict, so you can set None and ASE knows to ignore this, just activating the mulliken property keyword.
You can find further examples of the ASE NWCHEM wrapper in the ASE documentation.
